# Does party disposition affect priest and paladin powers of party members too?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I know that if you play a priest or a paladin in Pillars of Eternity, then your various dispositions will affect the strength of some of your powers and abilities (Holy Radiance in the case of priests, and Faith and Conviction in the case of Paladins).

I was wondering though if the dispositions you build as a result of your actions also affects the strength of abilities for any priests and paladins in your party as well, not just your main character?

So for example, if I hire a Kind Wayfarer paladin to join my team (favored dispositions are benevolent and passionate), will his or her Faith and Conviction become weaker (or at least no stronger) if I'm deceptive and cruel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Disposition only affects the Player Character. NPCs receive a fixed bonus which does not scale.